# JavaScript Bug on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, mobile-safari, ios4

I got this code:

```
function zeroPad(num, places) {
  var zero = places - num.toString().length + 1;
  return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join("0") + num;
}

result = "String begin ...." + zeroPad(o.m,2) + "Month" + ... + "String end ....";
```

And on all Browsers/Systems it works fine. It shows things like:
**06 Months 26 Days 09 Hours**

But on the iPAD1 with iOS 4.3.2 with Safari it shows:
**NaN Months NaN Days NaN Hours**
(not a number)

Whats wrong with these apple products, where is the mistake?

//Edit (for DCoder):
This is the code that generates the whole line i don`t think that helps a lot.

```
h = '<span class="f_normal"><span class="f_bold">' + zeroPad(o.m,2) + '</span> Month' + (o.m == 1 ? '': 's')+ '  <span class="f_bold">' + zeroPad(o.d,2) + '</span> Day' + (o.d == 1 ? '': 's') + '  <span class="f_bold">' + zeroPad(o.h, 2) + '</span> Hour' + (o.h == 1 ? '': 's') + '</span>';
```

The real question i search is this bug only appears on iPad?!

Comment: Can you show the code that actually generates the "06 Months 26 Days 09 Hours" line? Have you tried calling that function with hardcoded data (e.g. what does `zeroPad(5, 2)` return)? If that works correctly, then you need to look at how `o.m`, `o.h`, `o.d` are calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to cast your string as an integer:

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm